# Android + Kotlin + Hilt: Injecting into static methods classes

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm not very clear about the best way to inject into a static methods helper class (lets say a *Custom* class).

I'm kinda new to Kotlin, and as I've learnt we can access a method statically in two ways:

1. Object class.
2. Class + companion object.

To start, I'm not sure which one is the most recommended one (if there is a best practice regarding this), but my "problem" arises when needing to inject dependencies into a static method class.

Let's go with a simple example:

I have a static methods class called *AWUtils* (not decided if it should be an object class or a class with companion object yet though, and this will most likely depend on the injection mechanism recommended) with the next method:

```
fun setAmpersand2Yellow(text2Replace: String, target: String): String {
    return text2Replace.replace(
        target, "<span style=\"color:" +
                app.drawerFooterColor + ";\">" + target + "</span>"
    )
}
```

Here, app is the instance of my AppSettings class which holds all app configuration so, as you see *setAmpersand2Yellow* needs AppSettings, and of course I would't pass it as a parameter by any means, so it's a AWUtils dependence.

Using *AWUtils* as a class with companion object for the static methods I cannot inject directly AppSettings into company object as far as I know (at least I cannot do constructor injection, let me know if I'm wrong) and if I inject into companion object parent class (AWUtils) constructor then I don't know how to access those dependences from the companion object itself (the child).

If I use fields injection in AWUtils as a class then it complains than lateinit field has not been initialised and I don't know how to deal with this, because as far as I know lateinit fields are initialised in onCreate, which does not exist in this kind of classes.

One other possibility is to use an object with fields and set the dependencies values from caller in a static way before calling the method, for example:

```
object AWUtils {

    var app: AppSettings? = null

    fun setAmpersand2Yellow(text2Replace: String, target: String): String {
        return text2Replace.replace(
            target, "<span style=\"color:" +
                    app.drawerFooterColor + ";\">" + target + "</span>"
        )
    }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class OtherClass 
@Inject constructor(private val app: AppSettings) {
    
    fun AnyFunction() {
        var mystr = "whatever"
        AWUtils.app = app
        var yellowStr = AWUtils.setAmpersand2Yellow(myStr)
    }
}
```

In the end, I'm not sure on how to supply dependencies to a static methods class and which form of "static" class should I choose.

Edit 1:

Apart from my ApSettings class, I need a context, like for example in this next *isTablet* method:

```
val isTablet: String
    get() {
        return ((context.resources.configuration.screenLayout
                and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
    }
```

In the end, I need a *context* and my *AppSettings* (or any other custom classes) to be injected anyway in a class with static methods.

Edit 2:

I could do (from the activity):

```
AWUtils.context = this
AWUtils.app = app
var isTablet = AWUtils.isTablet
```

And it works, but rather to be in the need of assigning a value to two fields (or more) every time I need to call a static method, I would prefer the fields to be injected in any way.

That's what dependency injection is meant for, isn't it?

Edit 3: I'm starting to be fed up with Hilt, what is supposed would have been created to simplify our life, only makes our programming life much more complicated.

Comment: Just add `AppSettings` as a function parameter (or whatever you need for the utils method)?  Adding state to a utils class seems like a code smell - you want to keep it stateless so the client/caller will have predictable results.  This is not really a question about dagger .. this is just a tool/library to simplify dependency management.

Comment: Are you asking about "static"-like (quoted because no static in Kotlin) singleton access, such as `AWUtils.someCall(...)` because you prefer that approach, since it can be easily called anywhere in your code, or is that some requirement? Would you be okay by keeping `AWUtils` independent of `Context` and have an explicit (injectable) dependency for calls that require Context, AppSettings etc.?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Ma3x. As you mentioned, I prefer "AWUtils.someCall(...)" approach as it easy to call easy to read (that's the way I used to call method in custom classes when working with Java, the static way"). I could Inject AWUtils with Hilt, but I was said that not all your custom classes have necessarily to be injected. In the end, I'm trying to inject the classes that really needs injection, like repository, database, context and so, and leaving all other utilities (custom) classes to be accesible in the static way, but some of that classes have methods that require a context.....

Comment: Hello @Mark, I wouldn't like to be in the need to pass context or AppSettings as a method parameter, that's why we created dependency injection, and Context -for example- is clearly a dependency. Besides I don't think passing an instance of a class with all app configuration as a method parameter whenever is needed is a good approach, I'm using that class in many methods, so there must be a way for that class to be injected and accesible anywhere along the custom class. If not, I don't understand what dependency injection is meant for...

Comment: I cannot understand why something supposedly to be quite simple becomes so complicated. For me Hilt is meaning a lot of headaches, more headaches than happiness. What I just need is to inject a context and my AppSettings class in custom utility classes where I expect methods to be accesible in a static way, but its being a nightmare. If I inject them in constructor then cannot access them in "companion object", if I inject them in lateinit fields, then it complains context has not been initialised, in "companion object" cannot inject then either due to Hilt limitations so, I'm stuck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you clarified in the comments, you want to have your utils class accessible in an easy way across your codebase, so this answer will focus on that and on your original questions.

> I'm kinda new to Kotlin, and as I've learnt we can access a method statically in two ways: Object class or Class + companion object.

Kotlin does not have Java-style statics. One reasoning behind it was to encourage more maintainable coding practices. Static methods and static classes are also a nightmare for testing your code.

In Kotlin you would go with an object (but a class + companion object would work in the same way)

```kotlin
object AWUtils {
    lateinit var appContext: Context
    lateinit var appSettings: AppSettings

    fun initialize(
        appContext: Context,
        appSettings: AppSettings,
        // more dependencies go here
    ) {
        this.appContext = appContext
        this.appSettings = appSettings
        // and initialize them here
    }

    val isTablet: Boolean
        get() = ((appContext.resources.configuration.screenLayout
                and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)


    fun setAmpersand2Yellow(text2Replace: String, target: String): String {
        return text2Replace.replace(
            target, "<span style=\"color:" +
                    appSettings.drawerFooterColor + ";\">" + target + "</span>"
        )
    }
}
```

Since this object should be accessible across the whole application it should be initialized as soon as possible, so in `Application.onCreate`

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
class Application : android.app.Application() {
    // you can inject other application-wide dependencies here
    // @Inject
    // lateinit var someOtherDependency: SomeOtherDependency

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // initialize the utils singleton object with dependencies
        AWUtils.initialize(applicationContext, AppSettings())
    }
```

Now anywhere in your app code you can use `AWUtils` and `AppSettings`

```kotlin
class OtherClass { // no need to inject AppSettings anymore
    
    fun anyFunction() {
        val mystr = "whatever"
        val yellowStr = AWUtils.setAmpersand2Yellow(myStr)

        // This also works
        if (AWUtils.isTablet) {
            // and this as well
            val color = AWUtils.appSettings.drawerFooterColor
        }        
    }
}
```

There is another way in Kotlin to write helper/util functions, called [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions).

Your `isTablet` check might be written as an extension function like this

```kotlin
// This isTablet() can be called on any Configuration instance
// The this. part can also be omitted
fun Configuration.isTablet() = ((this.screenLayout
        and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
        >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)

// This isTablet() can be called on any Resources instance 
fun Resources.isTablet() = configuration.isTablet()

// This isTablet() can be called on any Context instance
fun Context.isTablet() = resources.isTablet()
```

With the above extension functions in place the implementation inside `AWUtils` would be simplified to

```
    val isTablet: Boolean
        get() = appContext.isTablet()
```

Inside (or on a reference of) any class that implements `Context`, such as `Application`, `Activity`, `Service` etc., you can then simply call `isTablet()`

```kotlin
class SomeActivity : Activity() {
    fun someFunction() {
        if (isTablet()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And elsewhere where `Context` or `Resources` are available in some way, you can simply call `resources.isTablet()`

```kotlin
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {
    fun someFunction() {
        if (resources.isTablet()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

> Edit 3: I'm starting to be fed up with Hilt, what is supposed would have been created to simplify our life, only makes our programming life much more complicated.

Yeah, Hilt is focusing on constructor injection and can only do field injection out-of-the-box in very limited cases, afaik only inside Android classes annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint` and inside the class extending the `Application` class when annotated with `@HiltAndroidApp`.

Docs for `@AndroidEntryPoint` say

> Marks an Android component class to be setup for injection with the standard Hilt Dagger Android components. Currently, this supports activities, fragments, views, services, and broadcast receivers.

If you feel that you need a lot of field injection, because you are working with "static"-like objects in Kotlin, consider using Koin instead of Hilt for your next project.

Comment: I tried your solution of using an object for AWUtils and initialising it in Application class onCreate and it worked perfectly @Ma3x, thanks for that and for such a great and detailed explanation, and let me ask you another question to have it clear: Following the example of my AWUtils custom utilities class, do u think it's better to use it as an object (like you proposed) or to create a "Provides" for it and inject it wherever is needed (the same for all custom utility classes)? I ask because I've been told is not necessary 2 inject everything, but I'd like to know your thoughts about that

Comment: @DiegoPerez I think you should use it in the way you find it easier. You are correct, it's not necessary to inject everything, you would inject components that need to be replaced by mocks or fakes in tests or components that use a different implement. in different build flavors, such as dev/sit/uat/prod builds (maybe `AppSettings` would be different per environment, but that's something you would know/decide). It's more effort to inject, but has its pros, but if your `AWUtils` uses only one impl. of itself and its dependencies and causes no problems in tests, then you don't have to inject it.

Comment: Thanks once more @Ma3x. Excellent explanation.